# Importing modules with dashes

Tags: swift

I'm trying to import a Some-Module.framework, but the dash in the name is giving me trouble.

```
import Some-Module // unexpected expression after unary operator
import Some_Module // no such module
```

Renaming it in `module.modulemap` fixes the compiler errors, but fails to link. How can such a name be imported without renaming and rebuilding the framework?